# Handling multiple user URL inputs that then need to be split and processed individually

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm newer to Python so please be easy on me senpai, since this is probably a simple loop I'm overlooking. Essentially what I'm attempting to do is have a user input a list of URLS separated by commas, then individually those URLS get joined to the ending of an API call. I have it working perfect when I remove the .split for one address, but I'd love to know how to get it to handle multiple user inputs. I tried setting a counter, and an upper limit for a loop then having it work that way but couldn't get it working properly.

```
import requests
import csv
import os

Domain = input ("Enter the URLS seperated by commas").split(',')

URL = 'https:APIcalladdresshere&' + Domain 

r = requests.get(URL)
lm = r.text
j = lm.replace(';',',')

file = open(Domain +'.csv', "w",)
file.write(j)
file.close()

file.close()
print (j)
print (URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to comment and ask what you mean by it not working properly (I'm guessing you mean something that I've mentioned down below), but maybe if you have something like a list of domains and then looking for a specific input that makes you break the loop (so you don't have an upper limit like you said) that might solve your issue. Something like:

```
Domains = []
while True:
    domain = input ("Enter the URLS seperated by commas: (Enter 'exit' to exit)")
    if 'exit' in domain.lower():
        break
    else:
        Domains.append(domain.split(','))
Urls = []
for domain in Domains:
    URL = 'https:APIcalladdresshere&' + domain
    Urls.append(domain)    #or you could just write Urls.append('https:APIcalladdresshere&' + domain)
```

But then the line `URL = 'https:APIcalladdresshere&' + Domain` will throw a `TypeError` because you're trying to add a list to a string (you converted `Domain` to a list with `Domain.split(',')`). The loop above works just fine, but if you insist on comma-separated urls, try:

```
URL  = ['https:APIcalladdresshere&' + d for d in Domain]
```

where URL is now a list that you can iterate over.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Essentially pretty close to what you typed up, I keep pulling a syntax error on True for some reason no clue why though when I don't have a need for parentheses or spacing when I'm attempting your solution.

Comment: @scyonidee oh oops, that's because the w in `while` was capitalized. Fixed.